# Aligning <input type="text"> and <select></select>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to align a selectbox and a textbox which I add to a form dynamically with javascript, but i can't get them to align properly.

css-code:

```
select
{
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left:6px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    width: 122px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;   
    font-size:13px; 
}

input[type="text"]
{
    width: 122px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left:7px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Html-code:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="headline" placeholder="Headline" value="<?=$_POST['Headline']?>" autofocus required>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <select>
        <option value='1'>option1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input name="Create" id="Create" type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

Javascript-code where I add the extra input fields:

```
function AddCatchInput($id)
{
var container = document.getElementById("myForm");
var submitbutton = document.getElementById("Create");

var select = document.createElement("select");
select.setAttribute("name", "Select"+$id);
select.setAttribute("id", "Select"+$id);
select.classList.add('FishSelect');
var option;

option = document.createElement("option");
option.setAttribute("value", "1");
option.innerHTML = "name";
select.appendChild(option);

// Create an <input> element, set its type and name attributes
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.name = "Weight" + $id;
input.placeholder = "Weight";
input.classList.add('FishWeight');



container.removeChild(submitbutton);
container.appendChild(select);

container.appendChild(input);
container.appendChild(submitbutton);
}
```

And what I end up with is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHagL.jpg

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Can you put your code into http://codepen.io/ or http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can look at a working example? Thanks.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/11013617

Comment: @PressingOnAlways it's that hard to copy and paste?

Comment: http://we.tl/vVtbliDHo9

Comment: @Gadgetster wasn't sure was it a complete working example. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `vertical-align:top;` to the both elements.

Comment: Did not help. Thanks anyway for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
select
{
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left:6px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    width: 129px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;   
    font-size:13px; 
}

input[type="text"]
{
    width: 122px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-left:7px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```